# My cart items are duplicated. How do I increment an item that is already in my cart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am seeking to achieve an answer I'm sure is very simple, but I've spent hours trying to figure out the matter as well as researching and reading the angularjs docs. All that I am trying to do is increment a cart item if it already exists within the cart's array. I'm assuming I am to use the forEach method, but the tactics I've used have proven useless. Could someone please guide me as to how I may achieve this? Code is below.

Note: I have already attempted the similar post on this site, but it has not helped me.

### Controllers.js

```js
.controller('cartCtrl', function ($scope, Cart) {
    $scope.items = Cart.getItems();

    $scope.getCartTotal = function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            var product = $scope.items[i];
            total += (product.price * product.quantity);
        }
        var result = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
        return result;
    };

    $scope.getTax = function () {
        var tax = 0
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            var product = $scope.items[i];
            tax += (product.price * product.quantity) * 0.075;
        }
        var total = Math.round(tax * 100) / 100;
        return total;
    };

    $scope.getOrderTotal = function () {
        return +parseFloat(this.getCartTotal() + this.getTax());

    };

    $scope.addQuantity = function () {
        $scope.item.quantity++;
    };

    $scope.subtractQuantity = function () {
        if ($scope.item.quantity > 0) {
            $scope.item.quantity--;
        }
    };
   
})

.controller('detailsCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $stateParams, Data, Cart) {
    $scope.detail = Data.getItem($stateParams.productId);

    $scope.addToCart = function (productId) {
        var found = false;
        var values = Cart.itemList;

        angular.forEach(values, function (orderedItem) {
            if (Cart.itemList._id == productId) {
                found = true;
                Cart.itemList.quantity += 1;
            }
        });
            if (!found) {
                Cart.addItem({ id: $scope.detail.id, price: $scope.detail.price, title: $scope.detail.title, img: $scope.detail.cover, quantity: 1 })
            }

    };

    
  
    
    
});
```

### Services.js

```js
.service('Cart', function (Data) {
    var itemList = [{
        id: ''
    }];
    var Total = 0

    return {
        addItem: function(newObj){
            itemList.push(newObj)
        },
        getItems: function () {
            return itemList;
        },
        setItem: function (value) {
            itemList = value;
        },
        getTotal: function () {
            return Total;
        },
        updateItems: function(item){
            this.items.push(item);
        },
        setTotal: function (value) {
            Total = value;
        }
    };

})

.service('Data', function () {
    var productList = [
    {
        title: 'iPhone 6',
        cover: 'img/iphone6.png',
        description: 'Apple Device of the New Age',
        price: 459.99,
        spec1: '4.7-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit widescreen Multi-Touch display with IPS technology',
        spec2: 'New 8-megapixel iSight camera with 1.5µ pixels',
        spec3: 'A8 chip with 64-bit architecture. M8 motion coprocessor',
        spec4: '1080p HD video recording (30 fps or 60 fps)',
        id: 0
    },
 {
     title: 'iPhone 6 Plus',
     cover: 'img/iPhone-6-Plus.png',
     description: 'Apple Device of New Age 2',
     price: 499.99,
     spec1: '5.5" LED-backlit IPS LCD Multi-Touchscreen Shatter proof glass, oleophobic coating',
     spec2: 'iOS 8, Dual-Core 1.4 GHz Cyclone (ARM v8-based) Processor, Chipset: Apple A8, PowerVR GX6650 (hexa-core graphics) Graphics',
     spec3: '8 Megapixel Camera (3264 x 2448 pixels) w/ Autofocus, Dual-LED (Dual tone) Flash + Front-Facing 1.2 Megapixel Camera, 720p, burst, HDR',
     spec4: 'Internal Memory: 128GB, 1GB RAM',
     id: 1
 },
    {
        title: 'iPad Air',
        cover: 'img/iPadAir.png',
        description: 'Apple iPad Air 2',
        price: 299.99,
        spec1: 'Fingerprint-resistant oleophobic coating Display',
        spec2: '16 GB Flash Memory, 1 GB RAM Memory',
        spec3: '10-hour battery life, 1.00 pounds',
        spec4: 'Apple iOS 7; 9.7 Retina display; 2048 x 1536 resolution',
        id: 2
    },
    {
        title: 'Dell Inspiron 15.6"',
        cover: 'img/dellLaptop.png',
        description: 'This is a laptop made by Dell',
        price: 499.99,
        spec1: 'Intel Core i5-4210U 1.70 GHz Turbo Boost up to 2.70 GHz, 3MB Cache, Intel HD Graphics 5500',
        spec2: '8GB PC3-12800 DDR3L 1600MHz SDRAM, 1TB 5400 rpm Hard Drive, Multiformat DVD¡ÀRW/CD-RW drive, 2 USB 2.0, 1 USB 3.0',
        spec3: '15.6 in Full HD LED-backlit touchscreen with Truelife (1920 x 1080), 10-finger multi-touch support, 720p HD Webcam, HDMI',
        spec4: 'Newest 802.11 AC Gigabit Wifi, 1G LAN Ethernet, Bluetooth 4.0, Waves MaxxAudio, Media Card (SD, SDHC, SDXC)',
        id: 3
    },
    {
        title: 'Galaxy S6 Edge',
        cover: 'img/galaxy-s6-edge.png',
        description: 'Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge',
        price: 399.99,
        spec1: 'Android v5.0.2 (Lollipop), Quad-Core 1.5 GHz Cortex-A53 + Quad-Core 2.1 GHz Cortex-A57 Processor, Chipset: Exynos 742, Mali-T760 Graphics',
        spec2: '5.1-inch Super AMOLED Curved Edge, Multi-Touchscreen with Fingerprint sensor, Samsung Pay and Protective Corning Gorilla Glass 4',
        spec3: '16 Megapixel Camera (2988 x 5312 pixels) + Front-Facing 5 Megapixel Camera with Dual-Video, Auto HDR, Panorama, and Optical Image Stabilization',
        spec4: 'Internal Memory: 32GB, 3GB RAM (not expandable)',
        id: 4
    }
    ];
     
   
    return {
        sendData: function (data) {
            productList = data;
        },
        getData: function () {
            return productList
        },
        getItem: function (id) {
            return productList[id];
        },
        addToCart: function (item) {
            productList.push(item);
        }
    };
   
})
.service('BlankService', [function(){

}]);
```

Finally, seldom do my Fiddles work, so here is an image of said issue.Thanks a ton for those willing to help!

[Picture of working cart, but with duplicated items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P02ai.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the addQuantity function an id then run the foreach loop in the function like so:

```
$scope.addQuantity = function (id) {
    cartItems.forEach(function (item, index) {
        if(id === item.id)
            cartItems[index].quantity++;
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Justin. This only affects the quantity when I tap the "plus" ion that is next to the quantity of the item in the cart. How do I make sure that if someone adds the same item to the cart through the product details page, it just increments the quantity itself and doesn't add another duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out! I analyzed @JustinHerter attempted solution and gave it a simple modification. All I had to do was manipulate my detailsCtrl's syntax because I hadn't even realized that while I was trying to call the Cart array, I forgot to include () after calling the function.Also, since I am using the master details pattern on local items in my "Data" service, I forgot that I could call the current state's id using the $scope.detail I inserted just above my addToCart function. So i merely was able to search my cart array for the current state ($Scope.detail) id, and voila, it worked! Thanks to the immense amount of similar situations and problems I found here, I was able to solve my own problem. Snippet is below.

```js
.controller('detailsCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $stateParams, Data, Cart) {
    $scope.detail = Data.getItem($stateParams.productId);


    $scope.addToCart = function (product) {
        var found = false;

        var items = Cart.getCart();

        angular.forEach(items, function (obj, index) {
            if (obj.id == $scope.detail.id) {
                items[index].quantity += 1;
                found = true;
            }
        });
            if (!found) {
                Cart.addItem({ id: $scope.detail.id, price: $scope.detail.price, title: $scope.detail.title, img: $scope.detail.cover, quantity: 1 });
            }

            $ionicPopup.alert ({
                title: 'Message',
                template: 'The item was added to the cart'
            })
```